# how to use python list comprehensions replace the function invoke inside of "for" stmt?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Sorry, I just found the

id = [conn.cursor() for x in range(100) ]

also works, so my concern will not be a problem anymore. 
Thanks for all of your answer, all of you are really fast.

---

All,

```
id = [(conn.cursor(),x) for x in range(100) ]
>>> id
[(<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x01D14DA0>, 0), (<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x01D14DD0>, 1), (<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x01D14E00>, 2), (<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x01D14E30>, 3), (<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x01D14EC0>, 4), (<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x01D14EF0>, 5),     <omitted>
```

but I do not need the id[1] col actually, and I do not want use the

```
for x in range(100):
    id.append(conn.cursor())
```

for some reason, do you think I can use the list comprehension to get what I want?
Also similiar question, if I want to invoke one function 100 times.

```
def foo():
    pass

for x in range(100):
    foo()
```

Can that "for" be rewrite to a list comprehensions style either?

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to avoid the name `id` as it is a [built-in function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second question

List comprehensions are used for generating another list as output of iteration over other list or lists. Since you want to run foo a numer of times, it is more elegant and less confusing to use for .. in range(..) loop.

**If you are interested in collating the return value of foo, then you should use list comprehension else for loop is good. At least I would write it that way.**

See the example below:

```
>>> [x for x in range(10)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> def foo(): print 'foo'
... 
>>> 
>>> [foo() for x in range(10)]
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>>
```

[Edit: As per request]

The iter version that was provided by eumiro.

```
>>> results = ( foo() for _ in xrange(10) )
>>> results
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x10041f960>
>>> list(results)
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>>
```

Comment: I recalled there is an iter version of the result collection, can you also mark it here?

Comment: @user478514: I have provided the example.

Comment: thanks, just want to know a little more, why (x for x in range(10)) return a generator? how it can be coded, I means how python know the () should return a generator not a tuple?

Comment: @user478514: Rather than repeat the answer here :) Read the SO at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension

Answer (score 1):

1.

```
cursors = [ conn.cursor() for _ in xrange(100) ]
```

2.

```
results = [ foo() for _ in xrange(100) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use the variable you are iterating over in your list iteration. This will work just fine:

```
id = [conn.cursor() for _ in range(100)]
```